# AppEngine Deployment Role with no access to data

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there a role in Google appengine which only has rights to deploy the application but does not have  access to data. As I understand all the roles viewer,developer and owner have access to data.

The use case is that because of security concerns many users will not want to share their data but the developers will want to give newer deployments.

Is there a way to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it can be done with GAE admin roles. The least privileged role: viewer has the right to view the data (but not to modify it). Also don't forget that if you have a right to upload code you can upload code that will give you access to the data.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such role. If you want to do this, you will need to give the code to your users to deploy themselves.

Note that even this doesn't solve the problem as you describe it, because the developer could trivially code in a backdoor that lets them examine the users' data. Ultimately, there is no way around this unless you're prepared to provide your source code: your users must trust you in order to use your app.